# Constructor ManagementObject(string path) fails to parse strings obtained from querying Win32_GroupUser class (C#)

Tags: c#, wmi, wql

So, I WMI query a remote machine to get the members of its `Administrators` group:

```
SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent = "Win32_Group.Domain='MACHINE_NAME',Name='Administrators'"
```

It returns the `PartComponent` property as strings. Here's the list (names changed for security). Domain users `joeblow` and `janedoe` are indeed local admins in that machine.

```
\\MACHINE_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="MACHINE_NAME",Name="localadmin"
\\MACHINE_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="OUR_DOMAIN",Name="Domain Admins"
\\MACHINE_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="OUR_DOMAIN",Name="joeblow"
\\MACHINE_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="OUR_DOMAIN",Name="janedoe"
```

I traverse the above results in a loop. Within it, I do the following:

```
ManagementObject isInThisUser = new ManagementObject(memberString);
```

I do that so I can extract the Domain and Name properties from each member object. In a perfect world, I would obtain the folowing list of strings as the end result:

```
\\MACHINE_NAME\localadmin
\\OUR_DOMAIN\Domain Admins
\\OUR_DOMAIN\joeblow
\\OUR_DOMAIN\janedoe
```

But here's what happens: the `ManagementObject` objects created by using that constructor come up **empty**! Domain, Name, Caption, everything, all `null`! Except for the first one (the local admin). For that one, the constructor works as advertised.

Why does that happen? Is it because the user making the query isn't a domain admin? (It *is* a local admin on the target machine, though. Actually, it's `OUR_DOMAIN\janedoe`.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works for me: after selecting PartComponent from associator Win32_GroupUser I do

```
string path = obj.Properties["PartComponent"].Value.ToString();
ManagementObject mo=new ManagementObject(path);
```

and mo contains all of the properties filled.  How do you fill memberString variable?